# Windows 8.1 Product Key Issue

Tags: windows-8.1

I bought the license from Microsoft's online store, installed it in my Mac via bootcamp. Ended up wiping my computer. Since I'm used to Mac, I was unaware that I needed to deactivate Windows to install it on another computer.

Fast forward a year

I need Windows again for school because I switched my major to computer science, but it says my product key is being used by another computer. I got Microsoft on the phone, and they activated it via another method, but they said that I would have to do this every time I want to move it to another computer and that there's a limit to how many times I can do it.

Basically, I want to know if there's any way at all to "free" my product key from a "computer" that's no longer operational?

Comment: You don't have to deactivate Windows that is automatically done when you activate it on different hardware.  Just use the phone activation method.  Even if you deactivated your installation, there is still a limit, to the number of times you can activate Windows new hardware.  How often are you going to install Windows on entirely new hardware, if its more then the limit, time to get another license.

Comment: Hasn't Microsoft already answered this question for you? "They said that I would have to do this every time I want to move it to another computer and that there's a limit to how many times I can do it."

Comment: The "this" I would have to do every time is call them and get them to override the restriction. I was looking for a way to disassociate my product key from the old machine.I don't plan on installing it a ton, but at least one more time when I get my external SSD.

Comment: Basic paradigm shift. [Mostly, not invariably] Apple ties a product to a user; Microsoft ties it to a machine. You will just have to get used to that essential difference. Change machine - Apple don't care, MS want a phone call.

Comment: @user3107922 - There is a simple command you can use to disassociate the license with the machine.  Even if you use that command, if the hardware is vastly different, you will still have to call.  Plenty of tutorials on what the command is though.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft is pretty strict about how their product keys are used these days. That's the only way I've been able to migrate windows 8 in similar situations in the past. Product keys get tied to Microsoft accounts, so it's a little tough to break away from it.

One thing you may want to consider is going through your school/university to get another copy of Windows 8 or 7. Usually schools, especially in computer science programs, offer services where students can download full versions of software for free, including Windows 7, 8, and pretty soon 10. The university I attend offers a ton of different software choices and accompanying keys. You may want to see if you have access too.

Comment: Windows 8.0 and Windows 8.1 licenses are not tied to your Microsoft Account....the only exception might be, if you purchase them through the Microsoft Store and even then its only because its connected because you purchase a digital copy the connection would end there.